# How can I make Bootstrap 4 cards all the same height of the parent container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 Beta to set up a series of cards that must look like following layout:

[image]

As the second image at the bottom depicts, I am having issues to make the cards in the middle column responsive to the height of the parent container. As you can see, the bootstrap card body of the 2 little cards at the top disappear and the image in the card at the bottom stretch by itself. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate any help:

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="./assets/hands.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text"> Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 flex-column flex-wrap">
    <div class="d-inline-flex h-50 ">
      <div class="card w-50">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="./assets/hands.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>

      </div>

      <div class="card w-50">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="./assets/hands.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column h-50">
      <div class="card align-self-stretch">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="./assets/hands.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top img-fluid " src="./assets/hands.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text"> Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.col-md-4{
 max-height: 357px;
 }
```

See jsfiddle in [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tfpqz2f5/8/)

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: haven't looked too closely but i don't think cards are the issue. i think you just need 3 columns, the 2 outer ones at 100% height, the 2 cards or divs in the middle at 50% height.

Comment: @wazz Thanks. Well, there are actually 3 columns only.The 2 outer columns and the cards in the middle are within a single column. For the middle column, the 2 cards at the top are inside a div with flex direction horizontal and the card at the bottom within a div with flex direction vertical. I set up a fiddle as well. Thx.